# Is Content-Type meta tag important if responce headers include content-type?

Tags: header, content-type, metatag

At the moment we set content-type in our responce headers, a bit like this...

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
```

We also have this at the top of html pages...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I've left the rest of the page out.

I know that we don't strictly speaking need the meta tag at the top of the html page.

However, do I need to leave it there really, due to known browser bugginess / problems etc? I'd like to take it out to avoid character encoding being set in 2 different places, but need to be sure it won't mess anything up somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including or removing the meta tag won't make any difference when the page is served from your site.

But if a user saves the page to disc, the Content-Type metadata will be lost. So continue to include the meta tag if you anticipate users saving your page.